Crop and save DNG images on Python
Working with DNG files, I am loading them into python script with RawPy, then using the raw_image() method to get a 2D array of the DNG values.
I need to crop this array and keep all the other metadata to be saved into another DNG file. To be clear I don't convert the array to RGB, just cropping the 2D array with raw DNG pixel intensities - hence no interpolation is done before cropping. Is this doable in python?
Thank you in advance!!!
NB: I am aware there are is another questions along the same lines as mine, but it is unanswered, a few years old and subtly different as I am not converting to RBG before cropping.

Since the Bayer color filter array is typically 2x2, you will need to keep your cropping boundaries on factors of 2.

While not fluent in php, I can give you the lines you need to follow: DNG is a TIFF like format (see spec), with the actual pixel (sample) data in Strips or Blocks, compressed or uncompressed. If you want to do it generic for all possible DNG files, it might be really hard. If you know the restrictions for these DNG files and they are uncompressed, you "simply" need to shift the sample data together with the required line length and adjust the ImageWidth, ImageHeight, BytesPerStrip... Use tiffdump, tiffinfo or exiv2 to display your DNGs and then maybe we can see what is the case.
